# Llenar <select> con PHP desde MYSQL usando dos archivos

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-select

Quiero llenar un `<select>` con los datos que tengo en la base de datos. Ya intenté poniendo un scrip dentro del HTML y funciona, sin embargo, para hacer más legible el código y poder acceder a los mismos datos en otras páginas (el `<select>` en cuestión se requiere en distintas páginas) he creado un script que contiene una función que en teoría debería generar los campos `<option>` pero al ejecutarlo no da el resultado deseado, es decir no se genera en la página en que lo llamo. El código de la función es:

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';

    function GenerarDependencias(){
        
        $sentence = "SELECT idDependencia, Nombre FROM Dependencias";
        $departments = mysqli_query($connection, $sentence);
        echo "<select>";
        foreach ($departments as $d) {
            echo "<option value=\"".$d['idDependencia']."\">".$d['Nombre']."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        mysqli_close($connection);
    }
?>
```

Para llamarlo en la página pongo el siguiente fragmento
`<?php GenerarDependencias(); ?>`
Como resultado la página se genera, lo único que no aparece son los datos en el `<select>`.
**Nota:** Justo antes del inicio del archivo html coloco `<?php include 'consultar.php' //script donde está la función ?>`

Comment: y que error te sale ???

Comment: La variable `$connection` no está disponible dentro de la función, debes enviarla como parámetro o, mucho menos recomendable, agregar `global $connection;` como primera línea de la función. Por cierto, te convendría usar `include_once 'connection.php';` porque me temo que se podría incluir ese archivo más de una vez.

Comment: @Triby ya lo he puesto como indicas y ha funcionado. Gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se solucionó mandando como parámetro la variable `$connection` a la función `GenerarDependencias();` ya que no está disponible para la función.
Aporte de @Triby